# Xamarin.forms - Gridview row height error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

My ContentPage have a Grid inside a ListView that contains a column (x:Name="stlNomeMiniatura") with a label and an image, as below:

```html
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="InventarioBensCelular.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="White">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="130" Background="#003399">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="40" Margin="7,10">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="Icone.png" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="48" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="40">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label x:Name="lblTitulo" Text="Inventário de Bens" FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                       VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Padding="0,-2,0,0"/>
                            <Label x:Name="lblSubtitulo" Text="Transmissão de Foto" FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                       VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Padding="0,-7,0,0"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40">
                        <ImageButton Source="ParametrosVerde.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                             HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32" Clicked="Parametro_Clicou"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <StackLayout WidthRequest="160" Margin="7,0">
                        <Frame x:Name="TiraFoto" CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="DarkGreen" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    Padding="0" HeightRequest="32" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="#E0FFE0" WidthRequest="160">
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TiraFoto_Clicou" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="10,0,0,0">
                                <Image Source="Camera.png" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="26" WidthRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                <Label Text="Tirar Uma Foto" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            TextColor="DarkGreen"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout WidthRequest="160">
                        <Frame x:Name="Sair" CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Red"
                    Padding="0" HeightRequest="32" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="#FFE8E8" WidthRequest="160">
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Sair_Clicou" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="10,0,0,0">
                                <Image Source="Sair.png" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                       IsAnimationPlaying="True"/>
                                <Label Text="Sair Programa" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            TextColor="Red"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Margin="0,-2">
                        <Frame x:Name="WiFi" CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="#003399"
                    Padding="0" HeightRequest="35" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="35">
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="WiFi_Clicou" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Image x:Name="imgWiFiStatus" Source="WifiVermelho.gif" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" 
                           VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="25" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0">
                <Label Text="Arquivos a Transmitir:" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"
                       VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="#003399"/>
            </Frame>
            <StackLayout Margin="10,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ListView x:Name="ltvArquivoLista" SeparatorVisibility="None" SelectionMode="None" HasUnevenRows="False" IsPullToRefreshEnabled = "True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="169"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="347"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                    <StackLayout  x:Name="stlNomeMiniatura" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Nome, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="15" 
                                               VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="#003399"/>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Miniatura, Mode=OneWay}" Aspect="AspectFit"
                                               VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                    </StackLayout>


                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                        <Image x:Name="cmdExcluirFoto" Source="{Binding BotaoExcluirImagem, Mode=OneWay}" Aspect="AspectFill"
                                               HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="Foto_Excluir_Clicou"/>
                                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Image>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In the .CS file I have the following piece of code that shows how the ListView ItemsSource is set with the ObservableCollection "Arquivo":

```
        public ObservableCollection<Arquivo> Arquivos = new ObservableCollection<Arquivo>();

    private List<string> ArquivosATransmitir = null;
    private DateTime TestaConexaoIntervaloDtInicio = Convert.ToDateTime("2000/01/01 00:00:00");
    private DateTime TestaConexaoIntervaloDtFim = Convert.ToDateTime("2000/01/01 00:00:00");

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DeviceInfo = new DeviceInfo.CDeviceInfo();

        Rotinas.File_Found("Inventario.ini", DeviceInfo.Info.Application.DataFolder, false, @"/");
        if (Rotinas.INIFileName == null)
        {
            Rotinas.INIFileName = DeviceInfo.Info.Application.DataFolder + @"/Inventario.ini";
            Rotinas.INI_Write("[SISTEMA]", "Titulo", "Inventário de Bens");
            Rotinas.INI_Write("[SISTEMA]", "Subtitulo", "Transmissão de Fotos");
            Rotinas.INI_Write("[SERVIDOR]", "IP", "192.168.0.22");
            Rotinas.INI_Write("[SERVIDOR]", "Porta", "1234");
        }

        TituloSistema = Rotinas.INI_Read("[SISTEMA]", "Titulo");
        Subtitulo = Rotinas.INI_Read("[SISTEMA]", "Subtitulo");
        ServidorIP = Rotinas.INI_Read("[SERVIDOR]", "IP");
        if (ServidorIP != "")
        {
            string auxPorta = Rotinas.INI_Read("[SERVIDOR]", "Porta");
            if (auxPorta != null)
            {
                ServidorPorta = auxPorta;
            }
            else
            {
                ServidorPorta = "1234";
            }
        } else
        {
            ServidorIP = null;
            ServidorPorta = null;
        }

        this.lblTitulo.Text = TituloSistema;
        this.lblSubtitulo.Text = Subtitulo;

        ConexaoServidor = new Connection();

        ConexaoServidor.FileTypeName = "Fotos";

        DiretorioArquivosATransmitir = DeviceInfo.Info.Application.DataFolder + @"/ArquivosATransmitir";
        if (!Directory.Exists(DiretorioArquivosATransmitir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(DiretorioArquivosATransmitir);
        }
        ArquivosATransmitir = Directory.GetFiles(DiretorioArquivosATransmitir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                              .Where(file => new string[] { ".jpg" }.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file))).ToList();
        if (ArquivosATransmitir.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int Ctr = 0; Ctr <= ArquivosATransmitir.Count - 1; Ctr++)
            {
                GridArquivo_Incluir(ArquivosATransmitir[Ctr]);
            }
        }

        ltvArquivoLista.ItemsSource = Arquivos;

        Testa_Conexao_Servidor();
    }
```

I would like it to appear as below:

[image: Xxpected appearance]

But, the GridView is shown with the rows height fixed with the images truncated, as below:

[image: Real appearance]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, sorry for my poor English.

Marcelo Camarate

Comment: Try to set the height to Stacklayout instead of row and column. Try `HasUnevenRows="True" `

Comment: Great tip Shaw.

Just using HasUnevenRows="True" in the ListView and changing RowDefinition Height to "*" in the GridView, solved my problem.

Thank you so much.

Marcelo Camarate

Comment: Note that if all rows are the same height, and you are willing to hardcode that, an alternative solution is to use RowHeight:  `<ListView RowHeight="169" ...>`. If you use RowHeight, don't set HasUnevenRows to True. HasUnevenRows is more flexible; it ensures ListView re-calculates each item's height as items are added. RowHeight sometimes gives smoother scrolling. (But for smoothness, first step is to NOT NEST layouts in an ItemTemplate. Instead of StackLayouts inside of Grid, Use two `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>`. Label Grid.Row=0, Image Grid.Row=1, trash can Column 1,Grid.RowSpan="2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to modify your code as follows:

1.change  the value of property `HasUnevenRows` from `False` to `True` for your Listview (`ltvArquivoLista`)

```
 HasUnevenRows="True"
```

2.change `Height` of `RowDefinition` from `169` to `*` or `Auto`;

```
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="347"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```